# Reverse a C-style string

Tags: c++

Write code to reverse a C-style string. (C-style string means that “abcd” is represented as five characters, including the null character.)
Nothing is printed out. Why?

```
void ReverseString(char *p){
    int length = strlen(p);
    for (int i = 0, j = length; i < j; i++, j--){
        swap(p[i], p[j]);
    }

}


int main()
{
    char a[] = "12345";
    ReverseString(a);
    cout << a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens to the null?

Answer (score 5):

You swap the `'\0'` terminator character that is at the end of your string to the very beginning. Thus `cout`, which prints until it finds the first `\0` character, prints nothing. Use `j = length - 1` to exclude it.

But even better: This is already implemented in the standard library:

```
void ReverseString(char *p) {
   std::reverse(p, p + std::strlen(p));
}
```

It is usually a very good idea to use algorithms over handcrafted code because it is much less error prone and often more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Reverse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("Xmen Logan");
    s.append('\0');

    System.out.println("C-style string---" + s);

    reverse(s);


  }

  public static void reverse(StringBuffer s) {
  int length = s.length();
  char[] chars = new char[length];

  int j = 0;
  for(int i = length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    chars[j++] = s.charAt(i);

  }

  String reverseString = new String(chars);

  System.out.println("Reverse String ------" + reverseString);

}
}
```

Comment: I think you've missed the C++ tag on the question!